# Power function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel

I know that there may be better ways of writing this do you think that this code is written well enough to be used in a real world application?

```
    var pow = function ( base, power ) {
    var result = 1;
    if ( power < 0 ) {
        return ( 1 / pow( base, -(power)) );
    }
    for ( var i = 1; i <= power; i++ ) {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) - it's built in (and roughly 5 times faster)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a power function with an integer exponent you can loop through the bits in the exponent instead of making a linear loop:

```
function pow(base, power) {
    if (power < 0) return 1 / pow(base, -power);
    var b = base, result = 1;
    while (power > 0) {
        if ((power & 1) != 0) {
            result *= b;
        }
        power >>= 1;
        b *= b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will only loop as many times as there are bits used in the exponent, for a value like 1000 that means 10 iterations instead of 1000.

Testing this with `pow(2, 1000)` in Firefox shows that it is about 70 times faster (but the built in method is still even 8 times faster).

Answer (score 2):

The code in the OP won't return a correct result for non-integer values of `power`: for example, `0.5` should return the square root of the number.

Sometimes you want to use the [Floating Point Coprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) for a calculation: instead of implementing an algorithm using software running on the CPU.